# Receive Bluetooth Audio stream and display waveform in real-time

Tags: android, html, css, bluetooth

I've been searching but can't seem to find any evidence that this has even been done before when considered in the context of HTML5.

Ideally i'd like to do this from a HTML5 app running on a mobile platform, it appears that it is not likely possible anytime soon, due to the lack of native support in HTML5 for calling hardware specific Bluetooth devices.

I suspect the way to do it is to make a native application that handles the Bluetooth and real-time waveform display, and embed a browser in the native app (android) to run the HTML5 interface.

Sounds simple, i'm sure it is not.

What i'd like to know is if you think this solution is the best approach for this, and if not, what is a better alternative?

Thank in advance.
Alex